# Is it possible to have an 'enter password' prompt in Windows 7 only while locked workstation, not while system start up?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, workstation

So I would like to be able to click **'lock workstation'** (I've even assigned a key on my keyboard for that so it takes a fraction of a second) and leave the computer and if anybody wants to use it he will need to enter password. But only **then**. I don't want to enter password when the the system starts up, it should log in automatically. Is that possible? Preferably without using software but not necessarily.

Comment: Windows has a built-in shortcut; WinKey+L.  There's no need to bind a hotkey unless that's too much for you.  As for your question, I don't actually remember how to set up automatic login in Windows 7 but I think that's your answer - there are ways to get it to log in automatically to a passworded account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, at a admin CMD or using "Run" type "control userpasswords2" this will bring up the User Accounts click "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computers" so it is off. When you boot up at the computer no passwords will be requested, but if you lock it or try to access it remotely you will still need the password to gain access.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for! :)
One minor alteration: the command is "control userpasswords2" (an "s" before "2"). Works great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's recommended but you can always leave your account without password (or use the automatic login suggested by Shinrai) and only request password to unlock the screeen saver.